# iptables rules timeout and removal

Tags: linux, bash, centos, iptables

Is there a way to have an iptables rule time out after so many seconds On Centos 7?

Basically I have IP address say 192.168.43.78 and I want to block it on tcp ports 80 and 443 for 3600 seconds.

Basically parsing log file for abuse then block for so many seconds. Is there a way to have an iptables rule automatically expire and remove itself so its gone from iptables -L?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/273324/how-to-make-iptables-rules-expire

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/933152/program-to-block-an-ip-temporarily-with-iptables